# Powershell subsequent usernames

Tags: powershell

I just started learning Powershell and I was wondering how to make a powershell script that scans the OU for users and picks the subsequent number.
For example when I have a "User1" and "User2" in my OU it will create "User3" when I run the script

Comment: StackOverflow is a place where developers share troubled code. Questions without code usually go to https://superuser.com/ or, in this case, to https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditto to what lit said.

However, since you are, know that this is a really simple task. Just select all users, sort by User number, extract the number part and add 1... Here is just on way to do it in a rough fashion.

```
# Using a user list, sort, extract the number via split and Regex and increment based on the highest number retruned
$UserList = 'User1','User3','User7','User8','User2','User5' 
'User' + ([int]((($UserList | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Last 1) -split '(?=\d)',2)[1]) + 1)
```

... but what if you delete a number user, then this could be a duplicate. Also using the numbering scheme you show, will not sort correctly as you get above single digits. So, you have to plan for the total number of uses expect and pad zeros for that. Of course I am just passing in a list, but of course one can just the AD cmdlets (either using RSAT or PSRemoting to a DC) to get that list to loop through.

```
'User9','User1','User3','User7','User8','User2','User5','User10' | Sort-Object

User1
User10
User2
User3
User5
User7
User8
User9

'User09','User01','User03','User07','User08','User02','User05','User05','User10' | Sort-Object

User01
User02
User03
User05
User05
User07
User08
User09
User10


'User009','User001','User003','User007','User008','User002','User005','User010' | Sort-Object

User001
User002
User003
User005
User007
User008
User009
User010
```

So, unless you are absolutely sure of this numbering and you never plan to delete a user, this will be a problem. If the above is true then you need to.

Yet all the above would only be known if you spent the time ramping up on PowerShell basics to limit / avoid all the confusion and frustrations you are going to run into.

So, stuff like this..

If the above is not clear. It's critical that if you are new, that you first spend the a few hours / days to ramp up to prevent a lot of unnecessary frustration and confusion you are going to encounter.

Do a search on [Microsoft Virtual Academy on PowerShell](https://mva.microsoft.com/search/SearchResults.aspx#!q=powershell&lang=1033) and [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beginning%20powershell) for no cost video training. 
Here are some other resources and advice:

- Free eBooks are available on this [site](https://leanpub.com/u/devopscollective)
- Read the full help file on any cmdlet you are trying to use
- Practice with the examples
- Read the helpfile again
- Pick up a few good books, like, ['PowerShell in a Month of Lunches'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1617294160).
- There are lots of free PowerShell eBooks on Microsoft's websites
  and others.

See also: [The PowerShell Survival Guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/183.windows-powershell-survival-guide.aspx)